# VBA Option Button does not get centered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet that has two rows of option buttons. Option buttons 1 - 11 are on row 7 and option buttons 12 - 22 are on row 9 of the sheet. My code loops through and centers each option button in its appropriate cell by calling the centerOfCell function. 
When I run my program Worksheets("Orders") gets passed into the CenterOptionButton procedure, and all of the option buttons get centered EXCEPT for option button 1. I cannot figure out why this happens.

```
Sub CenterOptionButton(wks As Worksheet)

Dim i As Byte

With wks
    Select Case .Name
        Case "RDC", "SKU"
            optionCount = 8
        Case "Orders"
            optionCount = 11
        Case Else
    End Select
    For i = 1 To optionCount
        .OLEObjects("OptionButton" & i).Left = centerOfCell(.Cells(7, i + 1))
        .OLEObjects("OptionButton" & i + optionCount).Left = centerOfCell(.Cells(9, i + 1))
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

If I then run the below procedure all by itself substituting out wks with Worksheets("Orders"), everything works perfectly. Any idea on what the issue could be?

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Byte

With Worksheets("Orders")
    Select Case .Name
        Case "RDC", "SKU"
            optionCount = 8
        Case "Orders"
            optionCount = 11
        Case Else
    End Select
    For i = 1 To optionCount
        .OLEObjects("OptionButton" & i).Left = centerOfCell(.Cells(7, i + 1))
        .OLEObjects("OptionButton" & i + optionCount).Left = centerOfCell(.Cells(9, i + 1))
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to copy the other option button and replace the first option button.  The issue might get resolved.  As for why it is happening I would not know.  Excel has been know to through up unknown errors.  I would normally recreate the file or object and the issue is usually solved.

Comment: Unbelievable. It worked!  I've been stepping through my code all day with the watch window scratching my head over this. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help.  Can you close this question.